# Push notification not receiving in Galaxy Nexus and Samsung S3 for my Android app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My Android application was already live in play store. Now I have updated that app with push notification using gcm and thus installed the updated version from play store in 5 devices (HTC, Micromax, Samsung S3, Galaxy Nexus, Samsung Ace plus).

As per our logic all the device ids are stored in the server side database. And those ids are finally being send to GCM server. Now when push notification is being send, I am only receiving in HTC and Micromax.

What is the problem for other 3 devices (Samsung S3, Galaxy Nexus, Samsung Ace)?

Answer (score 1):

Android 3.1 or higher, your application will not receive any broadcast until the user opens your application at least once.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: The system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. [...]

Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user (in Manage Applications).

Answer (score 0):

I am Not Sure what your exactly problem cause you do not have provided any type of code.

but make sure DateTime on the your Device DateTime should not be in be in the past.because GCM can't sync into the past Datetime. you have to reset it to present date time. Not Sure but have a try to it. may solve out your Problem.

Comment: MainActivity oncreate: checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");        
         GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext());        
         GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext()); regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
        if (regId.equals(""))            
            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID);
        else
        Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");

Comment: GCMIntentservice:   @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) 
     dact.new Pushnotification().execute(registrationId); To send this id to the server side  GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);   protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {      
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");       
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

Comment: Manifest permission: android.permission.INTERNET android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS android.permission.WAKE_LOCK package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE(permission and uses-permission)  package.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE